# VBA Code Adjustment under Office 2016 ActiveX component can't create object VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First off, my code runs fine until I installed Office 2016. Now, as soon as I try to use GETObject (in my case within Excel) I get the Error "***ActiveX component can't create object***". I already checked 'adjustemts to make' porting VBA code to 2016 and found [this solution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238610/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application).

Now my code snippet:

```
'*************NEW_Start
Dim intSection As Integer
Dim intTries As Integer
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 ' Enable error handler for this procedure:
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' Launch Microsoft Excel, giving it focus:
Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Excel.EXE", _
    vbMinimizedFocus 'other options for starting with
    'focus: vbMaximizedFocus and vbNormalFocus
  ' Move focus back to this form. (This ensures the Office
'  application registers itself in the ROT, allowing
'  GetObject to find it.)
Me.SetFocus

' Attempt to use GetObject to reference the running
'  Office application:
intSection = 1 'attempting GetObject...

'*************NEW_End
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

'*************NEW_Start
intSection = 0 'resume normal error handling


'Necessary for WIN > 97
If PowerPoint.Application.Version >= 9 Then
    'window must be visible
    PowerPoint.Application.Visible = msoTrue
End If
'*************NEW_End
```

with

```
'*************NEW_Start
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
'*************NEW_End
```

on top.

This still does not work, he cannot find 'Me.'. Anyone who can help me get "GetObject" working under 2016?

[image]

Comment: Where are you running your code from?

Comment: I run my code from Excel

Comment: From a module? From an userform? ... your code is incomplete and we are missing context.

Comment: Sorry, the code has hundres of lines code. I know it is difficult. I use it from a module that I trigger with a button within a worksheet.

Comment: There is no `Me` object in modules, that is why you code cannot work. The Shell should launch PowerPoint, not Excel, since you want an instance of PowerPoint. The test should be `If PPApp.Application.Version >= 9 Then`...